# How to upgrade scripts from iwconfig to iw?

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I have this script to print a formatted string representing my actual wifi copnnection and it's strength:

```
#! /run/current-system/sw/bin/nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i fish -p fish

set active (ip addr | awk '/state UP/ {print $2}' | sed 's/.$//' | head -n 1)

if test -n $active
    set essid (iwconfig $active | awk -F '"' '/ESSID/ {print $2}')
    set strength (iwconfig $active | awk -F '=' '/Quality/ {print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 1)
    set bars (expr $strength / 10)
else
    echo "No device up"
    exit 1
end

switch $bars
    case 0
        set bars "[----------]"
    case 1
        set bars "[/---------]"
    case 2
        set bars "[//--------]"
    case 3
        set bars "[///-------]"
    case 4
        set bars "[////------]"
    case 5
        set bars "[/////-----]"
    case 6
        set bars "[//////----]"
    case 7
        set bars "[///////---]"
    case 8
        set bars "[////////--]"
    case 9
        set bars "[/////////-]"
    case 10
        set bars "[//////////]"
    case "*"
        set bars "[----!!----]"
end

echo $essid $bars
```

It works fine however I changed my Linux distro to `NixOS` where `iw*` commands are deprecated so we only have `iw` command.

In my searches I found this command: `iw <interface> station dump` that shows me a lot of information but now exactly what I need.

It doesn't show my actual `AP` and signal ios shown as dBm with negative number.

How can I upgrade my old `iwconfig` command to the `iw`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/866005/wireless-connection-link-quality-what-does-31-70-indicate), we have the following:

> The cfg80211 wext compat layer assumes a signal range of -110 dBm to -40 dBm, the quality value is derived by adding 110 to the signal level

So with that in mind, the following (based on sample output of the iw command):

```
set essid (iw dev $active link | sed -n 's/[[:space:]]*SSID:[[:space:]]*//p')
set dbstrength (iw dev $active link | awk '$1 ~ /signal:/ { print $2 }')
set quality (math -s0 \( 110 + $dbstrength \) \* 10 / 70)
```

Will give you a value that will *max out* at 10, but you'll almost never get to 10, because it will round down. If you want it to round up for values like 9.6, add 0.5 to the value, before multiplying e.g.

```
$ set dbstrength -41
$ math -s0 \( 110 + $dbstrength \) \* 10 / 70
9
$ math -s0 \( \( 110 + $dbstrength + 0.5 \) \* 10 \) + 0.5
10
```

Comment: That makes more sense. I din't know about `iw dev <interface> link`! That solved my problem.

Comment: Could you please add the solution for `SSID`too? I solved as: `set essid (iw dev $active link | awk '$1 ~ /SSID/ { $1=""; print $0 }')`